# AngularJS select DOM element which belogs directive by tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, dom

Is there a way to select DOM element which belongs directive from I call select command?

As example - I got two directive. Eeach of them got `<input>` inside directive `view.html`.

*view1.html*

```
<input></input>
```

*view2.html*

```
<div>other input<div>
<input></input>
```

I got controllers declared in directives, which I use to handle stuff.

first (called from view1 directive)

```
$scope.selectView1Input = function(){
     var input = angular.element('input');
}
```

second (called from view2 directive)

```
$scope.selectView2Input = function(){
     var input = angular.element('input');
}
```

But in bouth situations it selecting the same input filed (I expected his behaviour, because it looks like just dom selector, so)

I don't want to use `id`s. Just simple tags, so, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why you don't use ng-model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery or the build-in jqLite to select to element:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var input = element.find('input');
            …
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: oh, I like it!
I calling controler function fon input chnage, and pass into controller function link on element I found using `.find()` function! nice

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$event` while calling the function from the directive.
Call the functions with $event as argument.

```
ng-click="selectView1Input($event)"
```

(if you are calling the function on click).

your functions will look like:

first (called from view1 directive)

```
$scope.selectView1Input = function(event){
     var input = $(event.target);
}
```

second (called from view2 directive)

```
$scope.selectView2Input = function(event){
     var input = $(event.target);
}
```

Comment: ope I don't use click there

Comment: How are you calling that function from the form?

Comment: it's just example code. actuall I got situation where one `canvas` in `1st directive view ` and other `canvas` in `2nd directive view`. Want to get 2nd canvas on input (on `2nd view` ofc) and update it with text I write

Comment: Using `ng-model` may help in this case. Use different model in both the input directives.

Comment: still dont understand how would it help with element selection

Comment: can you show little bit of your code, that would help to understand the situation a bit more.
otherwise add `ng-model="input1"` and `ng-model="input2"` in input directives of view1 and view2 respectively. and use `$scope.input1` and `$scope.input2` to get the respective values.